# How to use reverse foreign key relationship twice in one query

Tags: python, django

I've the models defined as follows:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name_a = models.CharField()

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name='aa')
    name_b = models.CharField()

class C(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, related_name='bb')
    name_c = models.CharField()
```

I'm making a RESTful webservice for model A and I've a queryset defined as

```
queryset = A.objects.prefetch_related('aa').all()
```

But I want data from model C as well. But I'm not sure how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can traverse relationships with the double underscore:

```
queryset = A.objects.prefetch_related('aa','aa__bb').all()
```

It becomes clearer without using related names:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    name = models.CharField()

class C(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
    name = models.CharField()

A.prefetch_related('b_set','b_set__c_set').all()
```

Example from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

```
>>> Restaurant.objects.prefetch_related('pizzas__toppings')
```

Where `Pizza` has a Many-to-Many relationship with `Toppings`.